# Problem whit instalatión of GridInsfrastructure DNS/NIS name service

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, rac

When trying to install the Grid Infrastructure 12, I have the following problem:

[image]

This is the description of error:

```
DNS/NIS name service - This test verifies that the Name Service lookups for the Distributed Name Server (DNS) and the Network Information Service (NIS) match for the SCAN name entries.  Error: 
 - 
PRVG-11826 : DNS resolved IP addresses "" for SCAN name "scan" not found in the name service returned IP addresses "192.168.0.222,192.168.0.221,192.168.0.220"  - Cause:  The name resolution setup check for the indicated SCAN name failed because one or more of the indicated IP addresses obtained from DNS could not be found in the IP addresses obtained from the name service on the system as configured in the ''/etc/nsswitch.conf'' configuration file.  - Action:  Make sure all the DNS resolved IP addresses are present in the IP addresses obtained from the name service on the system as configured in the ''/etc/nsswitch.conf'' configuration file by reconfiguring the ''/etc/nsswitch.conf'' for the indicated SCAN name. Check the Name Service Cache Daemon (/usr/sbin/nscd) by clearing its cache and restarting it. 
 - 
PRVG-11827 : Name service returned IP addresses "192.168.0.222,192.168.0.221,192.168.0.220" for SCAN name "scan" not found in the DNS returned IP addresses ""  - Cause:  The name resolution setup check for the indicated SCAN name failed because one or more of the indicated IP addresses obtained from name service on the system as configured in the ''/etc/nsswitch.conf'' configuration file could not be found in the IP addresses obtained from DNS.  - Action:  Make sure all the name service resolved IP addresses obtained from the ''/etc/nsswitch.conf'' configuration file are present in the DNS resolved IP addresses by reconfiguring ''/etc/nsswitch.conf'' configuration file for the indicated SCAN name. Check the Name Service Cache Daemon (/usr/sbin/nscd) by clearing its cache and restarting it. 
 - 
PRVG-11826 : DNS resolved IP addresses "" for SCAN name "scan" not found in the name service returned IP addresses "192.168.0.222,192.168.0.221,192.168.0.220"  - Cause:  The name resolution setup check for the indicated SCAN name failed because one or more of the indicated IP addresses obtained from DNS could not be found in the IP addresses obtained from the name service on the system as configured in the ''/etc/nsswitch.conf'' configuration file.  - Action:  Make sure all the DNS resolved IP addresses are present in the IP addresses obtained from the name service on the system as configured in the ''/etc/nsswitch.conf'' configuration file by reconfiguring the ''/etc/nsswitch.conf'' for the indicated SCAN name. Check the Name Service Cache Daemon (/usr/sbin/nscd) by clearing its cache and restarting it. 
 - 
PRVG-11827 : Name service returned IP addresses "192.168.0.222,192.168.0.221,192.168.0.220" for SCAN name "scan" not found in the DNS returned IP addresses ""  - Cause:  The name resolution setup check for the indicated SCAN name failed because one or more of the indicated IP addresses obtained from name service on the system as configured in the ''/etc/nsswitch.conf'' configuration file could not be found in the IP addresses obtained from DNS.  - Action:  Make sure all the name service resolved IP addresses obtained from the ''/etc/nsswitch.conf'' configuration file are present in the DNS resolved IP addresses by reconfiguring ''/etc/nsswitch.conf'' configuration file for the indicated SCAN name. Check the Name Service Cache Daemon (/usr/sbin/nscd) by clearing its cache and restarting it. 

  Check Failed on Nodes: [node2,  node1]  
Verification result of failed node: node2  Details: 
 - 
PRVF-4664 : Found inconsistent name resolution entries for SCAN name "scan"  - Cause:  The nslookup utility and the configured name resolution mechanisms, as defined in /etc/nsswitch.conf, returned inconsistent IP address information for the SCAN name identified.  - Action:  Check the Name Service Cache Daemon (/usr/sbin/nscd), the Domain Name Server (nslookup) and the /etc/hosts file to make sure the IP address for the SCAN names is registered correctly. Clear the stale IP addresses from the name service cache using the command ''/usr/sbin/nscd -i hosts''. 
 - 
PRVF-4664 : Found inconsistent name resolution entries for SCAN name "scan"  - Cause:  The nslookup utility and the configured name resolution mechanisms, as defined in /etc/nsswitch.conf, returned inconsistent IP address information for the SCAN name identified.  - Action:  Check the Name Service Cache Daemon (/usr/sbin/nscd), the Domain Name Server (nslookup) and the /etc/hosts file to make sure the IP address for the SCAN names is registered correctly. Clear the stale IP addresses from the name service cache using the command ''/usr/sbin/nscd -i hosts''. 
Back to Top  
Verification result of failed node: node1  Details: 
 - 
PRVF-4664 : Found inconsistent name resolution entries for SCAN name "scan"  - Cause:  The nslookup utility and the configured name resolution mechanisms, as defined in /etc/nsswitch.conf, returned inconsistent IP address information for the SCAN name identified.  - Action:  Check the Name Service Cache Daemon (/usr/sbin/nscd), the Domain Name Server (nslookup) and the /etc/hosts file to make sure the IP address for the SCAN names is registered correctly. Clear the stale IP addresses from the name service cache using the command ''/usr/sbin/nscd -i hosts''. 
 - 
PRVF-4664 : Found inconsistent name resolution entries for SCAN name "scan"  - Cause:  The nslookup utility and the configured name resolution mechanisms, as defined in /etc/nsswitch.conf, returned inconsistent IP address information for the SCAN name identified.  - Action:  Check the Name Service Cache Daemon (/usr/sbin/nscd), the Domain Name Server (nslookup) and the /etc/hosts file to make sure the IP address for the SCAN names is registered correctly. Clear the stale IP addresses from the name service cache using the command ''/usr/sbin/nscd -i hosts''. 
Back to Top
```

Everything is a test environment, I am using dnsmasq to assign us nameserver, when performing ping tests between the servers, this is it is successful bi-directionally.

Node1 to Node2

```
[grid@node1 gridinfrastructure]$ nslookup node2
Server:     192.168.0.10
Address:    192.168.0.10#53

Name:   node2
Address: 192.168.0.100

[grid@node1 gridinfrastructure]$
```

Node2 to node1

```
[root@node2 ~]# vi /etc/resolv.conf
[root@node2 ~]# nslookup node1
Server:     192.168.0.10
Address:    192.168.0.10#53

Name:   node1
Address: 192.168.0.10
```

This is the configuratión of my Node1

[image]

This is the configuratión of my Node2

[image]

This is the resolv.conf of the node1

```
[grid@node1 gridinfrastructure]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
#nameserver 181.70.124.110
#nameserver 200.13.249.101
nameserver 192.168.0.10
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
#nameserver 127.0.0.1
[grid@node1 gridinfrastructure]$
```

This is the resolv.conf of the node2

```
[root@node2 ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
#nameserver 181.70.124.110
#nameserver 200.13.249.101
nameserver 192.168.0.10
[root@node2 ~]#
```

This is the status of dnsmasq:

```
[root@node1 ~]# systemctl status dnsmasq.service
● dnsmasq.service - DNS caching server.
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-08-02 11:21:00 -05; 27min ago
 Main PID: 5080 (dnsmasq)
    Tasks: 1
   CGroup: /system.slice/dnsmasq.service
           └─5080 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -k

Aug 02 11:21:00 node1 systemd[1]: Started DNS caching server..
Aug 02 11:21:00 node1 dnsmasq[5080]: started, version 2.76 cachesize 150
Aug 02 11:21:00 node1 dnsmasq[5080]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus no-i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset aut...t inotify
Aug 02 11:21:00 node1 dnsmasq[5080]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Aug 02 11:21:00 node1 dnsmasq[5080]: ignoring nameserver 192.168.0.10 - local interface
Aug 02 11:21:00 node1 dnsmasq[5080]: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53
Aug 02 11:21:00 node1 dnsmasq[5080]: using nameserver 8.8.4.4#53
Aug 02 11:21:00 node1 dnsmasq[5080]: read /etc/hosts - 0 addresses
Aug 02 11:21:00 node1 dnsmasq[5080]: read /etc/rac.dns - 15 addresses
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[root@node1 ~]#
```

I tried to validate with my teacher, but he definitely could not help me, and he tried everything I have found on the network, at some point he told me to disable IPV6, disable them, but it did not work, I turn to you because I could not skip that part, and I feel too frustrated.

Comment: Does this happen in the pre-install check, or during the install? Sometimes the checks just don't work correctly and you can tell the installer to ignore the error. There should be a more detailed error message in the installer log, too. Grid Infrastructure also requires a virtual IP address for each cluster node, and three additional virtual IP address for the cluster, in addition to the actual node addresses. They need to be configured in a round-robin and all point to the cluster DNS name (e.g. myrac.local.com).

Comment: Indeed, it shows a detailed of the errors (update the post).

This is the configuration file I have:

192.168.0.10 node1
192.168.0.11 node1-vip
10.0.0.10 node1-priv
172.16.0.10 node1-asm

192.168.0.100 node2
192.168.0.101 node2-vip
10.0.0.100 node2-priv
172.16.0.100 node2-asm

192.168.0.200 node3
192.168.0.201 node3-vip
10.0.0.200 node3-priv
172.16.0.200 node3-asm

192.168.0.220 scan
192.168.0.221 scan
192.168.0.222 scan

and indeed, I have 3 ips for each node of the cluster, public, private and asm.

Suddenly the round robin setup escapes me.

Comment: What do you get back for `nslookup scan` on each node? In some versions you can also get away with putting everything in /etc/hosts and not using DNS at all, at least for the actual software installation.

Comment: Here's a link describing round-robin setup in dnsmasq: https://forum.netgate.com/topic/145999/dns-resolver-domain-with-multiple-ip-s-round-robin

Comment: Name: node1
Address: 192.168.0.10
> node1-priv
Server: 192.168.0.10
Address: 192.168.0.10 # 53

Name: node1-priv
Address: 10.0.0.10
> node1-asm
Server: 192.168.0.10
Address: 192.168.0.10 # 53

Name: node1-asm
Address: 172.16.0.10
> node2
Server: 192.168.0.10
Address: 192.168.0.10 # 53

Name: node2
Address: 192.168.0.100
> node2-priv
Server: 192.168.0.10
Address: 192.168.0.10 # 53

Name: node2-priv
Address: 10.0.0.100
> node2-asm
Server: 192.168.0.10
Address: 192.168.0.10 # 53

Name: node2-asm
Address: 172.16.0.100

Comment: I know I could put them in the hosts file, but it wouldn't be the idea.

I think that could cause me problems in the future, right?

How should I put it in the hosts file so I don't get this problem.

Comment: what is the actual output of nslookup on each node? that is the test that the installer is running, and it is getting apparently getting different or inconsistent results. The hack of putting everything in the host files is mostly to get you through the install; you just define everything like you would for any other host. Technically you could define your round-robin configuration in your tnsnames.ora file on the clients; it would just be more complicated than if it was handled by the DNS.